# Sparql : To display the name in the last of the sorted list if its firstname is empty

Tags: sparql

In my code i have bound first,middle and lastname into a single name and i sort it using name.

I want to sort the bound names in ascending and the name which doesnt have 1st name should be displayed at the end of the sorted list.

Please share your ideas for solving this issue.

My code:

```
bind ( COALESCE(?firstName, "") As ?firstName1).

bind ( COALESCE(?middleName, "") As ?middleName1).

bind ( COALESCE(?lastName, "") As ?lastName1).

bind (concat(str(?firstName1),str(?middleName1),str(?lastName1)) as ?name).

}

order by (regex(" " ,?firstName1) && bound (?name))
```

In the output though the name whose 1st name is empty appears in the end yet the rest of the names are not sorted in asc order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it, you want to sort the names in lexicographic order (order by first name, then by middle name, then by last name) with one exception:  instead of putting entries with *no* first name at the beginning, you want to put them at the end.  If this is correct, you want an ordering condition like:

```
ORDER BY DESC( bound( ?firstName )) ?firstName ?middleName ?lastName
```

This is some RDF to work with in which `:fn`, `:mn`, and `:ln` stand for for first name, middle name, and last name, respectively:

```
@prefix : <http://www.example.org/>.

:aaa :fn "A"; :mn "A"; :ln "A".
:aab :fn "A"; :mn "A"; :ln "B".
:aba :fn "A"; :mn "B"; :ln "A".

:_aa          :mn "A"; :ln "A".
:_ab          :mn "A"; :ln "B".
:_ba          :mn "B"; :ln "A".
```

This SPARQL for the data that binds `?firstName` optionally, and orders as I described above:

```
PREFIX : <http://www.example.org/>

SELECT ?firstName ?middleName ?lastName
WHERE {
             ?x :mn ?middleName .
             ?x :ln ?lastName .
  OPTIONAL { ?x :fn ?firstName . }
}
ORDER BY DESC( bound( ?firstName )) ?firstName ?middleName ?lastName
```

Calling the data `names.n3` and the query `names.sparql`, here are the results I get when I run the query on the data with Jena's ARQ:

```
$ /usr/local/lib/apache-jena-2.10.0/bin/arq --data names.n3 --query names.sparql
-------------------------------------
| firstName | middleName | lastName |
=====================================
| "A"       | "A"        | "A"      |
| "A"       | "A"        | "B"      |
| "A"       | "B"        | "A"      |
|           | "A"        | "A"      |
|           | "A"        | "B"      |
|           | "B"        | "A"      |
-------------------------------------
```

You can still do the sort this way even if you're projecting `?name` and not any of `?firstName`, `?middleName`, or `?lastName`.  For instance, the query

```
PREFIX : <http://www.example.org/>

SELECT ?name
WHERE {
             ?x :mn ?middleName .
             ?x :ln ?lastName .
  OPTIONAL { ?x :fn ?firstName . }

  bind ( concat( str(coalesce(?firstName, "_")), str(?middleName), str(?lastName) ) as ?name).
}
ORDER BY DESC( bound( ?firstName )) ?firstName ?middleName ?lastName
```

produces

```
---------
| name  |
=========
| "AAA" |
| "AAB" |
| "ABA" |
| "_AA" |
| "_AB" |
| "_BA" |
---------
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Joshua Taylor !

Comment: @ranjani Glad I could be of help, and welcome to StackOverflow!  If an provided answer answers your question, it's good to mark it as accepted (by clicking the arrow next to the answer).  Happy SPARQLing!